# Reading video from specific frame onwards OpenCV python

Tags: python, opencv, video-processing

I'm trying to use Opencv3.4 to read a .mpg file of several hours, but I want to skip the first thousand frames (approx 70 min), before actually reading and writing the file. Does anyone know how to do this? I have tried using a count that increments on every frame and then read only if the count is larger then a certain number, but this solution would be terribly slow, and actually did not work either (it only skipped a few minutes instead of over an hour, could be my calculation is off, but I don't think so).

In the code I added as an image, I try to overlay dots onto the frames, but the dots should only start from 'first_frame' (which is clearly not the first frame, but the frame from which we start measuring). Any suggestion would be really appreciated!

[image: current code]

Comment: From specific FRAME* onwards. Apologies.

Comment: Please don't post images of code or data. Copy the text in your editor and paste it in your question - formatted as code (select the text and *type* `ctrl-k`). ... https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python/OpenCV is there a way to quickly scroll through frames of a video, allowing the user to select the start and end frame to be processed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983062/in-python-opencv-is-there-a-way-to-quickly-scroll-through-frames-of-a-video-all)

Comment: You should be able to use `set()` on the VideoReader to set the frame counter or the timecode https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set

Comment: 'cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 105760)' returns error: 'NameError: name "CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES"' is not defined. And  'cap.set(cv2.CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, 105760)' returns error: 'AttributeError: module 'cv2.cv2' has no attribute 'CV_CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES''

Comment: cap.set() is what I am looking for though! I just dont understand this error now..

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
long_video_path = "videos/long_video.mp4"
cap = cv.VideoCapture(long_video_path)
fps = cap.get(cv.CAP_PROP_FPS)
mins = 10
cap.set(cv.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, mins*60*fps)
if not cap.isOpened():
    print("Cannot open camera")
    exit()



while True:
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    # if frame is read correctly ret is True
    if not ret:
        print("Can't receive frame (stream end?). Exiting ...")
        break
    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv.cvtColor(frame, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Display the resulting frame
    cv.imshow('frame', gray)
    if cv.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break
# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```